# Wordpress how to change post status from pending to approved

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, hook

I need to change post status from `pending` to `approved` when create a new post and if author has a approved post before.

I have a function like this but the code doesn't work at all.

Please help:

```php
add_filter('wp_insert_post', 'change_post_status_when_insert_post_data',10,2);

function change_post_status_when_insert_post_data($data) {
    if($data['post_type'] == "post") {
      $posts_args = array(
        'author__in' => $id,
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'approved',
        'posts_per_page'  => -1,
      );
      $user_posts = get_posts($posts_args);
      $count = count($user_posts);
      if($count > 0) {
        $data['post_status'] = 'approved';
      } else {
        $data['post_status'] = 'pending';
      }
    }
  return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> the code doesn't work at all

Because

- `wp_insert_post` is an action hook not a filter hook. Therefore, using `add_filter` is incorrect.
- You asked `wp_insert_post` to give you two arguments, but you used one in your callback function.
- `$data` is the post `object`, it's not an `array`. You can NOT use it like `$data['post_type']`.
- `'post_status' => 'approved'` does NOT exist. [See the list of valid post statuses<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#status-parameters)
- What you're looking for is post status `publish` NOT `approved`.

The following code goes in the `functions.php` file of your theme.

```php
add_action('wp_insert_post', 'change_post_status_when_insert_post_data', 999, 2);

function change_post_status_when_insert_post_data($post_id, $post)
{

  $posts_args = array(
    'posts_per_page'  => -1,
    'author'          => $post->post_author,
    'post_status'     => 'publish',
  );

  $user_posts = new WP_Query($posts_args);

  $post_status = (('post' == $post->post_type) && ($user_posts->found_posts) && ('publish' != $post->post_status) && ('trash' != $post->post_status)) ? 'publish' : 'pending';

  if ('publish' == $post_status) {
    wp_update_post(array(
      'ID'            =>  $post_id,
      'post_status'   =>  $post_status
    ));
  }
}
```

The conditions that i used in order for a post to be published automatically:

- The `post_type` should be 'post'
- AND
- The author must already have at least one published post.
- AND
- The `post_status` should NOT be `publish` already.
- AND
- The `post_status` should NOT be `trash` either.

It's also worth mentioning that I used `WP_Query` and its property `found_posts` instead of using `get_posts` and `count` to figure out whether an author has already published a post or not.

---

This answer has been fully tested on wordpress `5.8.1` and works.